# Move CGRect to the bottom of the screen

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cgrectmake

I am running AdMob on my app, but the tutorial provided by google has the banner on top of the app, i want it at the bottom of the app/screen, i use rows 0 to 17, so anything after row 18 is fine.

This is the method that draws the ad if one was received:

```
-(void) adViewDidReceiveAd:(GADBannerView *)adView
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{adView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, adView.frame.size.width, adView.frame.size.height);
    }];
}
```

What would i need to do to have it displayed at the bottom of the screen?

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 2):

Set the Y position to the height of the screen minus the height of the view (in landscape orientation you need to use the width of the screen instead):

```
adView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height.y - adView.frame.size.height, adView.frame.size.width, adView.frame.size.height);
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are in the view controller:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{adView.frame = 
    CGRectMake(0.0, 
               self.view.bounds.size.height-adView.frame.size.height, 
               adView.frame.size.width, 
               adView.frame.size.height);
}];
```

Comment: nearly worked, its still showing the ad on top of my row 17, i need it to go down a bit further

Comment: Well, I don't know anything about your row logic. Depending on your layout and view programming language, you may have to use the window's bounds instead of self.view.